# Transformer power

Tags: transformer

I have 2 transformer at 4000 kva power and these transformer convert  34,5 kv to 3,15 kv. 
I need 400 v for my system and to get 400 v , I connect transformers ( their power 1000 kva and convert 3,15 voltage to 400 v ) to these 4000  kva transformers.
How many  transformers( at 1000 kva  3,15 kv  to 400v)can be supplied from these 2 pices 4000 kva transformers which they convert 34,5 kv to 3,15 kv?
Would you explain with formulas[image]

Comment: This smells like homework. Can you share what work you have done already?

Comment: Please try to rewrite your question. Transformers do NOT convert energy from 34 kV into 3,15 kV. They convert the voltage. So we have Power in kVA and Voltage in kV. It might be that you then can find your answer even yourself. Hint. The power rating is the most important factor here

Comment: Where do you keep these 4MW transformers that you have?

Comment: That's the problem the student has, a confusion between "energy", "power", and "voltage".

Comment: @AliChen And _that's_ when you know you are screwed on the finals or you take up your career in journalism instead and plague the articles with units and physical quantities, energy and power all mixed up.

Comment: Sorry for my english

Comment: I work in navyyard

Comment: Please name the vessels you've worked on so that, by choice, I'll never board them.

Answer (score 1):

Look how much (apparent) power you have on the two 34,5/3,15 kV transformers (KVA) and then look how many  3,15 kV/400V transformers you can hook up to come to the same value again in kVA. Remember you are looking for (apparent )POWER.

Note: The expressing "apparent" is added since kVA = Apparent Power and can be less then POWER wich is expressed in kW. The formula for this is kVA = kW * PF where PF can vary between 0 and 1.

Comment: VA isn't necessarily power.

Comment: @EMFields  I agree but did not want to complicate the situation even more for OP. Have adjusted the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have showed the two 4000 KVA transformers tied together on a common bus as if they are sharing the load. If the load is shared on a common bus or if the loads are equally distributed between the two 4000 KVA transformers, simply divide the total 8000 KVA by the connected individual branch transformer KVA (1000) to show that 8 transformers rated 1000 KVA each can be connected. Considering that the losses in the 1000 KVA transformers add to the load, they would not all be permitted to operate at full load at the same time, but the quantity or individual ratings should not be reduced for that. The diversity of the ultimate loads and protective devices should be sufficient. If there are two 4000 KVA transformer installed so that one is connected only if the other fails, you can only feed 4 branch transformers of 1000 KVA each.